# Opening up an exe through a .bat file in a network

Tags: batch-file

I'm getting fed up having to go into multiple computers to run the same exe and I'm wanting to simply open all of them up with a click of a button. I've already managed to pass my files between computers using a .bat and that works fine. What I'm after is just conformation that what I'm about to do is correct.

So far my bat file looks like this:

```
echo off
echo Sending to all Clients
START \\destinationPC\C$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\exefolder\test.exe
pause
```

What I'm confused about is if I run this; will it simply open up the required exe on the computer I've ran the .bat file from leaving me with multiples of the same exe open, or will it open up the exe on the computer that holds the exe? Where it will display on its own monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs a copy of the program, locally, but the code loads from the same location.

When you execute this, windows on the computer that you run the command from - will look at `\\destinationPC\C$\Users\Administrator\Desktop\exefolder\test.exe` and parse it to this determine the absolute location of the file in a same way as if the file was on the local computer. It will then (if it has the security privileges) do normal program loading.

In memory the code is loaded and the execution happens all on the computer that you are running the bat file file.

Edit:
To run that program remotely you can use a utility like [PSEXEC from sysinternals.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute
>   processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for
>   console applications, without having to manually install client
>   software.

Comment: So is there a way to open up an exe on a remote computer and have that exe run on the remote computer?